# Добавить картинки в таблицу Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Не могли бы подсказать как сделать чтобы в строке таблицы `<td>Приз</td>` отображалась картинка . Если просто вставляю ссылку на картинку , то она отображается в дальнейшем на каждой строчке , а требуется только на 1-2-3 строчки

```js
var CupApp = angular.module('CupApp', []);
CupApp.controller('CupCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.cups = [{
    "user": "Менеджер",
    "Total": 1715,
    "B_1011": 0,
    "B_1012": 0,
    "B_1013": 0,
    "B_1014": 0,
    "B_1015": 60,
    "B_1016": 0,
    "B_2021": 0,
    "B_2022": 60,
    "B_3031": 0,
    "B_3032": 0,
    "B_3033": 0,
    "B_3034": 0,
    "B_3035": 0,
    "B_3036": 0,
    "B_3039": 1595
  }];
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="CupApp" ng-controller="CupCtrl">
  <div id="container">

    <div id="Html1">
      <h2>Топ в компании</h2>
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
          <th>Менеджер</th>
          <th>Балы</th>
          <th>Приз</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="cup in cups | orderBy: '-Total' ">
    <td ng-style="$index < 3 ? {'font-size' : '16pt'}: ''">{{ $index + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{cup.Total}}</td>
    <td>Приз</td>
   </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я может ошибаюсь, но что мешает создать переменную для приза так же , как ты это сделал для баллов ? А по хорошему сделать бы массив объектов типа

`var array = [{ Name:"Vasia", Role:"Manager",Prize:url}]`

и его подставлять в репит как `<img src={{array.Prize}}/>`.  И тогда там где нужно у тебя приз будет null.(Можно еще ng-show поставить в img на наличие/отсутсвие приза)

**UPD**

Есть решение "влоб" - просто добавить ng-if пока $index < 3 выводить призы .

Comment: Если я делаю это как балы , то будут подставляться в каждую строку в таблице. А мне надо только на первые 3 строчки. Массив сам мне приходит в json файле , его изменить пока нет возможности)

Comment: Даже если и так, никто не запрещает тебе этот массив менять. Можно просто использовать json файл как источник данных, а внутри программы превратить их в удобный вид. Но есть решение "влоб" - просто ng-if пока index < 3 выводить призы

Comment: Да , через ng-if помогло. А я могу к вам еще обратиться за помощью с json и angular?

Comment: Пишите, если я смогу помочь =)

Comment: У меня страница берет данные json со страницы которая выгружается для меня в сеть ,к ней авторизация с логином и паролем. Я ни как не могу получить из нее данные , могу брать только из файла json лежащего в корневой папке сайта